# Map integration in MEAN STACK

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps-api-3, mean

I want to integrate a google map in my page. That it should be able to find the user's current location and send the data back. Since am using node I didn't get any good reference for that!

So kindly suggest me some best solutions  or good refernce

Answer (score 0):

since your are using angular , you can find plenty of google map modules in gihtub . angular Ui is a set of modules that will speed up your developement process, it already includes google map directive and other directives which you can use in your app

here is how to use it :
http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use

for sending the data back to node (express) , you have multiple options : socket io if you are using it , or a simple http post to your server will do the trick

just remember to use promise to wait for the data before you send it.

hope it helps!